# How to do validation in the WordPress theme customizer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a WordPress theme and I am working on the theme customizer for the theme options. I want to validate the inputs and to show an alert if the validation fails in the theme customizer.

This is what I have tried

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('custom_social_settings[facebook]',array(
          'default' => '',
          'type' => 'option',
          'sanitize_js_callback' => 'check_url'
         ));

function check_url(){
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             // My validation script
        });
    </script>

    <?php
}
```

The problem is when I load the page sanitize_js_callback gets executed twice. When will be the `sanitize_js_callback` will be invoked? It should be invoked only when I click the save button. Should I write script for the click event of the save button. Is there any better way to do validation in WordPress theme customizer? How to do a typical form validation in WordPress theme customizer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [customize_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register) hook and it shouldn't run twice because those callbacks (including `sanitize_callback`) should be executed (bound to) only when you save your data/submit the form. Well, if you are doing it using the hook and still now you are facing this problem then I think (maybe not best) you can check if the form is submitted or not (`isset($_post['submit'])`).

To sanitize a `url` (before saving in database) you can use [esc_url_raw](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url_raw) function. [Check Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and [this nice tutorial](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using a customize_register hook. Is there any way to show an alert box after validation? I am looking for a client side validation